# Bundling proj4js with webpack leads to "Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0"

Tags: webpack, proj4js

I try to include proj4js (2.5.0) as an ES6 module in a webpack (4.27.1) project.

```
import proj4 from 'proj4';
```

That leads to this error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/proj4/package.json
Module parse failed: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0 while parsing near 'module.exports = __w...'
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0 while parsing near 'module.exports = __w...'
```

What can I do to bypass this error?

---

Looking at issue reports on the proj4js github page it looks like the json-loader is executed twice since proj4js explicitly requires the package.json:

proj4js/lib/version.js:

```
export {version as default} from '../package.json';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by this loader in our webpack-config:

```
{
     test: /\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg|svg|xml|json)$/,
     use: ["url-loader"]
}
```

I excluded proj4 from this loader and it works.